# Simple proof of: if $ax\equiv ay \pmod{m}$, and $\gcd(a,m)=1$, then $x\equiv y$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm working on a proof of: "if $ax\equiv ay \pmod{m}$, and $\gcd(a,m)=1$, then $x\equiv y\pmod{m}$". Here's what I have so far:

Suppose $ax\equiv ay\pmod{m}$, and $\gcd(a,m)=1$

By definition, $ax = ay + mp$ for some $p\in\mathbb{Z}$

By definition, $ay = ax + mr$ for some $r\in\mathbb{Z}$

By Bezout's identity, it must be that $\gcd(a,m) = ax$

Similarly, it must be that $\gcd(a,m) = ay$

Therefore, $ax = ay$

Obviously, $x=y$

Q.E.D.

Is this ok?

Comment: Alternative proof: $m|a(x-y),\,(m,a)=1\Rightarrow m|(x-y)$. Seems no. Can you further clarify the step "By Bezout's identity, it must be that $\gcd(a,m)=ax$"?

Comment: Why does $\gcd(a,m)=ax$?  It clearly fails when, e.g., $a=1,m=2,x=10,y=0$, for example.

Answer (score 4):

The proof you gave may have a flaw: if $1=gcd(a,m)=ax=ay$, then $|a|=|x|=|y|=1$, which is not the case. By Bezout's Identity, from $ ax=ay+mp$ and $ay=ax+mr$, we can only imply $ax$ and $ay$ are multiplier of $gcd(a,m)$

The proposition you stated is a special case of a general proposition:

> if $ax\equiv ay (mod$ $m)$, then $x\equiv y(mod$ $\frac{m}{gcd(a,m)})$

Proof:

With the assumption we can have $m|a(y-x)$, therefore $\frac{m}{gcd(a,m)}|\frac{a}{gcd(a,m)}(y-x)$, which implies $\frac{m}{gcd(a,m)}|(y-x)$. i.e $x\equiv y(mod$ $\frac{m}{gcd(a,m)})$

This is basically due to Euclid's Lemma(which can be proven with Bezout's Identity):

> if $a|bc$ and $gcd(a,b)=1$, then $a|c$

Answer (score 3):

The quick proofs all use that $ax \equiv ay \pmod m$ is equivalent to $m | (ax - ay) = a(x - y)$.

If $m$ divides $a(x - y)$, and $m$ has no factors in common with $a$ (by hypothesis $\gcd(a, m) = 1$), then it must be that $m | (x - y)$.

But that's equivalent to $x \equiv y \pmod m$. QED.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really understand our OP K_M's attempted proof; I do it like this:

given that

$ax \equiv ay  \pmod m, \tag 1$

we have

$m \mid ax - ay = a(x - y) ; \tag 2$

and given that

$\gcd(a, m) = 1 \tag 3$

we also have

$\exists u, v \in \Bbb Z, \; au + mv = 1, \tag 4$

which is basically Bezout's identity; then multiplying this by $x - y$ yields

$a(x - y)u + m(x - y)v = x - y; \tag 5$

by (2),

$m \mid a(x - y)u, \tag 6$

and obviously

$m \mid m(x - y)v; \tag 7$

thus *via* (5),

$m \mid x - y, \tag 9$

which by definition means

$x \equiv y \pmod m. \tag{10}$